# this keyword in reactJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Hi I am confused about the 'this' keyword in ReactJS. I have the following code here for a simple counter in react.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class ButtonClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
    this.decrement = this.decrement.bind(this);
    this.state = { count: 0 };
  }
  increment() {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  }
  decrement() {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count - 1 });
  }
  render() {
    const showCountStatus = this.state.count;
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Click to increrment the button</p>
        <button onClick={this.increment}>Increment</button>
        <button onClick={this.decrement}>Decrement</button>
        <h1>{showCountStatus}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ButtonClass;

ReactDOM.render(<ButtonClass />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

The code works perfectly however, if I change the increment and decrement function to:

```
increment() {
    this.setState({ count: count+ 1 });
  }
  decrement() {
    this.setState({ count: count-1 });
  }

  Count is not defined error is shown
```

Any suggestions as to why? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

As the error message says, there is no `count` variable defined.

From what I understood, it seems like you want to increment by one from previous state.
Then you can get a reference to the previous state and use that value to increment by one.

```js
 increment() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ count: prevState.count+ 1 }));
  }
  decrement() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ count: prevState.count-1 }));
  }
```

Refer to [State Updates May Be Asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) for more details on where `prevState` is from and how it is used.

Answer (score 0):

The code which doesn't work, because `count` in `count + 1`, `count - 1` is not from `this.state` object `count` key. JS is trying to find inside the function scope the variable definition, and it did not find it and throwing the correct error.

So to access the state object key `count`, you always need to write it like `this.state.count`.